# setOnclicklistener for each Button in Listview

Tags: android, button, android-listview

I am facing a problem with  android listview. I have multiple Buttons inside my **ListView**  and I want to setclicklistener for each Buttons and retrieve their position in ListView.

ListItem.xml

```
<Button xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/btnList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textColor="#fff" />
```

MainActivity.java

```
mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                getApplicationContext(), R.layout.drawer_list_item,
                mPlanetTitles));
```

button `OnClickListener`

```
btnList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
               new DrawerItemClickListener();   
            }
        });
```

class `DrawerItemClickListener`

```
private static class DrawerItemClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener  {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
        MainActivity main= new MainActivity();
        main.selectItem(position);
        }
    }
```

Comment: post your code and what you have tried.

Comment: @Raghunandan I edit my code above)

Comment: and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: when i click button in listview. nothing happen

Comment: `MainActivity main= new MainActivity();` is wrong. also you click a button then you have  `new DrawerItemClickListener();` you are totally confused. You need to open a particualr activity on drawer item click. pls post what you need its very unclear

Answer (score 1):

Use this and the position in OnItemClick is the button's position in the list

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
    }
```

Comment: It seems @Vaseph just wants the listener a part of the row (the buttons)

Comment: @FD_ yeah you understand me).

Comment: @Vaseph Does my answer help? I added more details now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle the on click listener of the button inside the getview of the listview adapter, where you find the button using view.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID).
This is how you can do it :

```
Button yourButton= (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID); // be carefull to use the view of the listItem and not the activity in case the adapter is inside the Activity.
yourButton.setTag(position);// Any data associated with the button has to be added with setTag()
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                      Log.w("DEBUG_TAG", "Button Clicked at position : " + position);
                      //here you must use getTag() in order to extract the data set in the setTag()
            }
        });
```